# Select TH element of an ID within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, selector, getelementbyid

I am trying to select a TH element which does not have an ID, so I am using its parent TR element, all of this is within an iframe.
The code looks something like this:

```
<iframe id="gsft_main">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="hdr_incident" class="list_header " style="">
            <th class="" scope="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" align="center">
                <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    <a href="blabla">Link</a>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</iframe>
```

I am able to select it using this jQuery, but the point is to get away from including that lib.

```
$("#gsft_main").contents().find("#hdr_incident th:first-child");
```

But I can't when I try to do:

```
var main = document.getElementById('gsft_main').contentDocument;
main.getElementById('hdr_incident').getElementsByTagName('th')[0];
```

So I tried to use a querySelector, but no luck:

```
var main = document.getElementById('gsft_main').contentDocument;
main.querySelector("#hdr_incident > th");
```

One might think the "main" variable part is the issue, but I am able to select other elements using this code, so that shouldn't be the issue.

```
var main = document.getElementById('gsft_main').contentDocument;
main.getElementById('list_nav_incident');
main.getElementById('page_timing_div');
main.getElementsByClassName('timingDiv')[0];
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working in the iframe? (I am able to get this to work in a jsfiddle without the iframe part).

Comment: jQuery's first goal was to solve the issues you have now. If you want to do it your way, than go on, explore the web. I warmly suggest you [build](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/) your own jQuery library.

Comment: Usually iframes are used to load another page or url in to your own page. Nesting HTML inside of it only tells browsers that if they don't support the `iframe` tag to [render that content instead](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). Beyond that, iframes have a variety of different security and cross-domain mechanisms that often block the interaction between to pages (outer and inner). There are ways to work around those limitations like [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) or using frames hosted on the same domain.